# Warning message: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please find below the code i ran (Using: eclipse-java-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64  + IE 11)

```
public class SampleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\IEDriverServer\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver d1 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        d1.get("http://www.google.com/");
        WebElement element = d1.findElement(By.name("q"));
        element.sendKeys("selenium");
        System.out.println("Test Selenium");
    }

}
```

While running I got below logs

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.40.0.0
Listening on port 22795
Mar 26, 2014 7:04:27 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Mar 26, 2014 7:04:27 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
```

1. Why am i getting this warning messages all the time only in IE
2. While writing "Send Keys" string in "Search" text box its taking more than 5 secs for each character

Would appreciate any helpful note on these... :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should really only ask one question per post, particularly if your questions are unrelated, as the two you're asking about are. I've answered your first question. The second is thoroughly discussed in the comments of the issue tracking the problem in the project issue tracker, particularly [a comment that discusses the root cause in some detail](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5116#c21). The workaround for the "slow sendKeys" problem is to use the 32-bit version of `IEDriverServer.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

From a [blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/12/seeing-info-messages-in-log-does-not.html) that discusses this issue in great detail:

> There are two answers to this question, a short one and a long one.
>   The short one is, "Read the log message. It's clearly tagged as
>   'INFO', as in an informational message, and not indicative of any
>   problem with the code?" I find that this question often comes from
>   users of Eclipse, and that the Eclipse console has colored the message
>   red, and people are so conditioned to see "red == bad" that they react
>   to the format of the message rather than the content. The content of
>   the message is flagged at a level that means, "Hey, nothing is wrong,
>   we're just telling you about it."

For the longer, more detailed explanation, see the blog post, but it boils down to a race condition in bringing up an HTTP server, and using an HTTP client to poll for when that server is available to receive commands.